# POST a WS SOAP Javascript (jQuery) y gestionar respuesta

Tags: javascript, jquery, webservice, post

Necesito consumir unos WebService desde el código cliente de mi aplicación web, podría ser tanto desde javascript como jquery. La mayor parte de las operaciones que tengo que hacer son POST, y no sé como recoger la respuesta del WebService. Tengo el código de la respuesta aceptada en 
                             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example, del tipo a:

```
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://somesoapurl.com/', true);

        // build SOAP request
        var sr =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soapenv:Envelope ' + 
                'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                'xmlns:api="http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API" ' +
                'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                '<soapenv:Body>' +
                    '<api:some_api_call soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
                        '<username xsi:type="xsd:string">login_username</username>' +
                        '<password xsi:type="xsd:string">password</password>' +
                    '</api:some_api_call>' +
                '</soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    // alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
                }
            }
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.send(sr);
```

Pero tras ese send, ¿Cómo recojo la respuesta del WebService?

Comment: En teoría la respuesta debería gestionarla ese `onreadystatechange`. La llamada al webservice te devuelve un estado 200? ese `alert(xmlhttp.responseText);` debería mostrar los resultados

Comment: @David Ah vale, ese código está en onReadyStateChange, que se ejecutará cuando conteste el WebService. Era una cosa obvia, pero sin tu respuesta no me habría dado cuenta. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No hay de que, paso el comentario a respuesta de forma más detallada. @gabi13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` es un listener que se queda en espera y es llamada como callback de la funcion send() cuando esta cambia de estado, es decir, cuando recibe una respuesta del servicio web. Si se cumplen esas condiciones que tienes (readyState es 4 y status es 200) 
que son básicamente que haya una respuesta correcta con el estado http 200, entonces mostrara por un alert la respuesta que está en el objeto `xmlhttp.responseText`.

Como añadido, deberías poner un else para mostrar por consola algún error ya que al ser onreadystatechange en el momento en el que el estado cambie se ejecutará la función, lo que también incluye una llamada incorrecta. Una buena metodología incluye un buen manejo de errores. Podrías añadir el siguiente código.

```
if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
else {
    console.log("Error de llamada con código " + xmlhttp.status, xmlhttp.response);
}
```